# Deleting Questions After being flagged as duplicate or when the question is answered on the "suggested" questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, scope

So I've come to terms that I may not be the best Google searcher in the world and often end up having my questions flagged as duplicate, flagged as wrong category, downvoted to oblivion, or a combination of the three.

I say this as I just finished asking a question and, as I was preparing it, none of the suggested questions that appeared fit. However, after I submitted the question and it was posted, I noticed that I saw a question which fit my answer appear under "similar questions". I ended up deleting my own question and using that one instead.

Another instance that happened would be me doing a search on a Photoshop matter that I found a similar question asked and answered on Stack Overflow, only to see that my question was downvoted multiple times. I ended up having to ask a moderator (I believe) move the question for me to the appropriate site and reverse the downvotes.

I was wondering if it is a good practice, let alone acceptable, if I delete my question after it's been flagged by a moderator as duplicate question or wrong site (example: I post a photoshop (non-programming related) question on StackOverflow instead of the proper site)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you weren't able to find the question, even though you tried searching for it, then clearly it isn't easy enough to find. Your duplicate now serves as a very useful pointer to the "master" question. Hopefully people who use the search terms you tried will now find your question, and that will redirect them to the master question with the answers they seek.

So no, don't delete duplicates. Unless you really just didn't put any effort at all into searching. That'll be quite obvious; the two questions will basically have identical titles.

As far as obviously off-topic questions, yeah, feel free to delete those. Or don't; [an automatic process will take care of it for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

But I can't imagine the state of confusion that would cause you think that Photoshop was on-topic for a programming Q&A site.