# Is it worth flagging for a VLQ duplicate, deleted by its OP?

Tags: support, downvotes, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I came across [a question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616274/is-it-possible-to-send-bulk-whatsapp-message-using-php-code) (10k+ only link currently) where the OP has deleted it as it is a duplicate:

[image]

Apart from my spelling error of 'not', the OP was requested not to delete their question. From their comments it seems like the OP *really doesn't* want to lose any reputation from the downvotes.

---

The question itself is of low-quality, and is of a subject that's bound to attract downvotes (*bulk messaging [spam]*), but it still is a useful duplicate signpost for [sending bulk Whatsapp messages Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106184/sending-bulk-whatsapp-messages-android?rq=1).

I quickly browsed around, and found [Deleting Questions After being flagged as duplicate or when the question is answered on the “suggested” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261948/deleting-questions-after-being-flagged-as-duplicate-or-when-the-question-is-answ), which suggests that question deletion by the OP due to a duplicate is not acceptable:

> So no, don't delete duplicates. Unless you really just didn't put any
>   effort at all into searching. That'll be quite obvious; the two
>   questions will basically have identical titles.

[-Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261970/2422013)

I was initially going to flag one of the user's other posts to alert a moderator to the matter, but I'm unsure whether this particular case is actually deserving of moderator attention. Back to the user requesting users do not downvote their question; it might be worth seeing if this (*deleting downvoted questions*) is a pattern for this user. If so, they'll likely be hit with a question ban before long.

Is the 'post vandalism' in this case acceptable (***aka, low-quality duplicate being deleted***)? Is it worth flagging in the case a similar situation arises?

*In my opinion, the question in this particular case should be undeleted & dupe-hammered.*

Comment: No, this isn't vandalism. The user really did the site a favor- That was a pretty bad question. Now if they edited to be a better question _then_ deleted it, yes, that would be bad. But that's not good quality, so we lose nothing in it being deleted. As a side note, post vandalism instead refers to when a user edits and vandalizes a post by removing/replacing content and destroying what was already there.

Comment: Also, referring to your comment in the screenshot, I highly doubt any moderator will undelete that question unless it gets a complete face-lift to make it a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should generally assume that poorly-written, unanswered, heavily-downvoted questions will eventually be deleted by *someone*, regardless of whether or not they're duplicates. If the author doesn't do it, then 10K+ users probably will; if they don't, then one of the automatic deletion scripts will.

Good "signpost" duplicates are useful, but we're not really short of badly-written ones.

If you particularly want to *save* a question, then **edit it.** Make it look *good*, something that you and others are comfortable *upvoting*. That's gonna do a lot more long-term to preserve your signpost than getting into an argument with the author will.